# Java counting capital letters in a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am creating a text analyzer using java, what I'm  trying to do is to search through the text document, and count how many Capital letter there are.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(CapitalCount.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    int upperCaseCount = 0;
    int linecount = 0;

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        sc.nextLine();
        linecount++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
                upperCaseCount++;

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(upperCaseCount + "");
}
}
```

I think that i will have to do some sort of count on how many lines there are, this is why i have added a line count at the top, although I am unsure on how to implement this with the capital count that only works on the first line.

Comment: could you please provide an example for your input document and a related output you would expect.

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what the problem is. Does it error, or not produce the expected output?

Answer (score 8):

1. **Scan through every characters**
2. **Check if the characters are within Capital Letters Range.**

*You don't need CapitalCount class to scan a file.*

Below is my working solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        int count = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < line.length(); i++){
                if(line.charAt(i) >= 'A' && line.charAt(i) <= 'Z'){
                    count ++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of capital letters are : "+count);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, either close your `Scanner` resource, or use try-with-resources instead.

Comment: Previously, I was concerned with just the solution part but now I did @Tom.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary the internal loop to check if a letter i a capital letter.
Change

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
        upperCaseCount++;

    }
}
```

to

```
if (s.charAt(i) >= 'A' and s.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
    upperCaseCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(CapitalCount.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
 int upperCaseCount = 0;
 int linecount = 0;
 String lineInput = null;

 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  lineInput = sc.nextLine();
  linecount = lineInput .length();
  for(int i=0; i < linecount; i++)
      if (Character.isUpperCase(lineInput.charAt(i))) upperCaseCount++;
 }
 System.out.println(upperCaseCount + "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Character.isUpperCase()` method instead of doing it manually.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        int capitalCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            lineCount++;
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < line.length(); i++){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(i))) {
                    capitalCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of lines: "+lineCount);
        System.out.println("Number of capital letters: "+capitalCount);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried to call ".next(Pattern pattern)" method with pattern for capital letters?
Than I think you should count capital letter for every single line, so *before* for cycle..